# Visual Studio is not allowing to select the varialbe inside for each loop [By Mouse]?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2019

I am working in code and all of sudden it stopped allowing me to select the variables in for each loop.

[image: can't select variable service/passengers]

I am using VS Community 2019 
Version 16.5.4 on Windows 10

Comment: have you tried closing the file and reopen it? if it does not work try restarting VS

Comment: Can you provide the related code about you are using? Besides, I suggest that you can define the type directly in the loop instead of using var type.

Comment: @viveknuna This is happening randomly and that's why not a good idea to restart VS

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT, That's not an issue, I can put the type, in the screenshot check pointer on service variable, it should be allowed to be selected so I can copy service and replace at other places, however, I can not do that for some bug...